# Inverse of arithmetic functions

Tags: modular-arithmetic, inverse

Is  the function $\mathbb{Z}_7 \to \mathbb{Z}_7: x \mapsto x^3 \pmod 7$  a one–one correspondence? And if so, what is the inverse function?

Comment: It is not one-one. $1 \to 1$ and $2 \to 1$.

Comment: So what part of this question is giving you trouble?

Comment: It is one-one in a paper of springer 2016 .

Answer (score 2):

You write out the entire table for how this function acts.  It won't take long.

Here, I'll start it for you.

$\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline x&x^3\\\hline 0&0\\\hline 1&1\\\hline 2&?\\\hline 3&6\\\hline 4&?\\\hline 5&?\\\hline 6&?\\\hline \end{array}$